# Add a conditional field in JSON schema in draft-07

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am developing a schema for JSONs. I want to allow certain fields when some field have specific value.
For simplicity, let's say there is a required string field "Type".

1. I want to fail validation, if there some other fields than "Type" (or the ones I'll conditionally add).
2. If field "type" is "Type1", I want to allow having a new string field "val1". If JSON have other fields than those two, validation fails also.
3. I want to add more such conditions (e.g. when "type" is "Type2", add "val2" field); also make additional fields required or not; also add 2 or more fields. This shouldn't blow the schema.

E.g. this schema is allowed. If I add any field, it fails. If I remove any field, it fails. If I change "type" field, it fails.

```json
{
    "type": "Type1",
    "val1": "1"
}
```

I managed to write a schema for this using "unevaluatedProperties", which seems to works for me.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": ["type"],
  "unevaluatedProperties": false,
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "Type1"
          }
        },
        "required": ["type"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "val1": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": ["val1"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately I want to use a [validator](https://github.com/pboettch/json-schema-validator) in my c++ project. It supports only draft-07, while "unevaluatedProperties" is added in draft-09. So I need to rewrite this schema to draft-07, without "unevaluatedProperties".
Honestly, if you suggest any c++ validation library that supports draft-09, it also solves my problem.

I managed to add a single condition. Looks like it works.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "val1": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": ["type"],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "const": "Type1"
      }
    },
    "required": ["type"]
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "const": "Type1"
      },
      "val1": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": ["type", "val1"],
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": ["type"],
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
```

But unfortunately the schema blows up when I add 2-3 more, using this approach.

Do you have any ideas to do that?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not ready for prime time, this project was pretty close to completing their JSON Schema implementation. You may want to reach out to the maintainer. https://github.com/Neyn/neyson

Short of that, you can give this schema a whirl:

Prior to Draft-2019-09, `additionalProperties` was the keyword you are looking for but there is some funky behavior with it that you need to be aware of.

`additionalProperties` **does not** behave exactly the same as `unevaluatedProperties` with an `allOf` composed schema.  The biggest difference is
`unevaluatedProperties` can "look into" the subschemas defined in the array of schemas to "see" the properties defined in each subschema whereas `additionalProperties` **ONLY** looks at the root of the schema where `additionalProperties` is defined.

That means, in earlier versions of JSON Schema, you MUST define any properties in the subschemas of an `allOf` composed schema in order to effectively use `additionalProperties: false`. A `true` schema is sufficient for the validator to recognize the property definition and any additional constraints on the keyword will be evaluated and applied in the `allOf` subschema

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "val1": true
    },
    "required": [
        "type"
    ],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "const": "Type1"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "type"
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "val1": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "val1"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I tried this approach too, but this schema validates the json, even when both `"type": "Type0"` and `"val1": "s"` fields are present. I wanted to field `"val1"` be only allowed if field `"type"` is `"Type1"`.